# JavaScript how to transform String into a function

Tags: javascript, string, function, parsing, error-handling

I am doing a calculator for definite integrals, where I can add the function to integrate by using this interface.[Calculator interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebqS8.png)

The point is that once I call the function to integrate it recognizes it as a String and i cannot calculate over it. But if I add the function hardcoding it, it works perfectly fine.

```js
  prueba() {
    //**** this.cadena is the function I add by using the interface
    var sal = this.cadena;
    console.log(sal);
    var f = function (x) {
      //**** The comented return works perfecly fine
      //return 1/x;
      return parseFloat(sal);
    };
    var integrada = this.integ(sal, 1, 2);

    this.cadena = integrada;
    this.imprime();
  }
  integ(f, a, b) {
    var area = 0;
    var dx = 0.001;
    for (let x = a; x < b; x += dx) {
      area += dx * f(x);
    }
    return area;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below line

```js
var integrada = this.integ(parseFloat(sal), 1, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it did not wrok, finally i left the fuction as the comented return, this is for university, so i told the teacher to put the function hardcoding it